# Find a word and replace with words from file

Tags: shell, awk, sed, vi, replacewith

I have the task of creating a configuration file. The config file is a JSON file. Example below

```
"text": {
        "data": "Click Here",
        "size": 36,
        "style": "bold",
        "name": "text1",
        "hOffset": 250,
        "vOffset": 100,
        "alignment": "center",
        "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
    }
```

The configuration repeats with change in the "**style**" attribute of the json. So I am going to copy the above text say 50 times. I would then like to replace the "style" attribute with different styles inputted from another comma separated file as shown below.

```
bold,italic,cryptic
```

The output would then be

```
"text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
"text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "italic",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
"text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "cryptic",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
```

Is there a easier way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another solution using GNU awk for `gensub`:

```
awk -v RS= '
  NR==FNR { n = split($0, styles, /,/); next } 
  {
    for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
      style = "\"" styles[i] "\""
      print gensub (/(["]style["]: ).[^,]+/, "\\1" style, "G", $0); 
    }
  }
' style.txt config.file
```

You start off with a file called style.txt that has comma separated values of styles you want. You store them in an array. You proceed to iterate your config file and swap out the style segment and replace it with new pattern.

I hate to admit that JSONs are better parsed with a JSON parser using either Perl, Ruby or python, but posting this as a one-off option since you don't have any control over the config file.

Answer (score 3):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS= 'NR==FNR{t=$0;next} 
                     {n=split($0,styles,","); 
                      for(i=1;i<=n;i++) {s=t; 
                                         sub("bold",styles[i],s); 
                                         print s
                                        }
                     }' template styles
```

where template is the json formatted text and styles is a comma separated file (one or more rows).  Assumes "bold" only appears once in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what you want to apply it but you could read the json the same for each iteration and within that iteration change the value of Style where you need to. Just an idea.

Comment: Reading of json is beyond my control. I just provide the config file. So I am bound to do it in the file

Comment: If you can just modify the json file then I don't think there's much you can do. Wait to see if any one else knows a way. If you had any access to modify the file outside of the file(in the code) you coud simply use the put methog.
JSONObject date=  jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("day");
person.put("day", "Tuesday");